# Strange Java for loop format

Tags: java, syntax, for-loop, processing

I've come across a for loop structured in a way I've never seen before. I'm wondering if you can explain to me what it is doing? It is provided as one of the examples for verlet integration in Processing:

http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/17191

Here is the code:

```
for(VerletParticle2D p : physics.particles) {
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
}
```

Is it simply adding an 'p' particle until it reaches the amount that has been setup before?

Comment: What have you already searched for before posting the question?

Comment: @bluesman: In fairness to the OP, it's pretty hard to google for unfamiliar syntax, especially one that involves no special keywords.

Comment: @aix +1 for general truth, but second result by just typing "java for loop": [java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), where you'll learn that Oracle calls this an "enhanced for loop".

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I skipped just 'java for loop' as I thought that would only return a normal for loop. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @Schmooo and that's where aix is right by saying it's difficult to google for unknown syntax. The java for loop is what you knew there was, so you thought that search would only make you find those. I never downvoted you btw :)

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I didn't take offence. I was just saying why I didn't google so you didn't think I was an idiot. =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the so-called "for each" loop. It simply iterates over all elements of the collection (or array) `physics.particles`, assigning each element in turn to `p`.

For further information, see [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is the Java "For-Each" loop. It iterates over all elements in a collection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 3):

That is a `for-each` loop. It iterates over a collection.

In this case, the collection is physics.particles. `p` will represent the current object in each iteration. `VerletParticle2D` is the compiler type of the object.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop is iterating through the "Particles" in physics.particles and for every element in it, it is calling the ellipse function call.